# How do I open or convert a Microsoft Works .XLR spreadsheet to an Excel compatible format

Tags: openoffice

How do I open or convert a Microsoft Works .XLR spreadsheet to an .ODS spreadsheet? 
 Microsoft Works .XLR spreadsheet will not open In OpenOffice.

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice Calc and LibreOffice Writer can open .xlr spreadsheets and save them to .ods format. *LibreOffice is the most actively developed free and open source office suite, a project of The Document Foundation. It was forked from OpenOffice.org in 2010.*<sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice)</sup>

You may need to quickly change the width of the first column in the .ods spreadsheet by dragging it with the mouse.

If you want to stick with OpenOffice, you can run LibreOffice as a [portable app](https://portableapps.com/apps/office/libreoffice_portable) without installing it on your hard drive.